# Getting more devices in Apple Developer Company Account

Tags: udid, iphone-developer-program

Currently the Apple Developer Company Account offers its users to register 100 devices to provide ad-hoc distribution and testing of apps via provisioning profile. As of my understanding these devices remain in the account for 1 year, and even if deleted the space won't free up to add additional devices.

The question is now what can you do when your list is full but you still have clients/test persons to provide with beta apps before submitting to the app store?

Should I setup another company account? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are limited to 100 UDIDs per company account.
2. If you ask nicely they might give you another 10 discretionary (they did this for me).
3. When your renewal is due, you get the opportunity to remove devices that you no longer need. Do this BEFORE adding any new test devices.
4. If you buy another Developer account, and tie it into the team, this does not increase the UDIDs for the corporate account.
5. If you open another corporate account - this may work but I'd email support and ask for them to call you back to talk through the options.

It is ridiculous, compared to 10,000 beta test accounts on Windows Phone and zero restrictions on Android.